# Python - unable to use ctime to get last modified time

Tags: python

I'm learning Python (version 2.7.9 on win8) and currently going over the various `date` and `time` modules. I'm unable to get the last modified time of a file using `ctime`.
I'm facing this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'ctime'
```

Here are my imports:

```
import os
from os import path
from datetime import date,time, timedelta
from datetime import datetime
```

Script:

```
modTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("t.txt"))
print "t.txt was last modified at: " + modTime # This Doesn't work 

print datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getmtime("t.txt")) # This works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: `datetime.time has no attribute 'ctime'`. But the `time` module has a function `ctime`. You are shadowing the `time` module by the `from datetime import time` line.

```
>>> import time
>>> time  # refers to the *module*
<module 'time' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so'>
>>> time.ctime()
'Sun Feb  1 16:23:33 2015'
>>> from datetime import time
>>> time  # now we have a class of that name
<type 'datetime.time'>
>>> t = time()
>>> t.isoformat()
'00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, but they don't give you good advice about how to use imports, which is to not use 'from' and instead use the fully-qualified names, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> It's much better to:
>
> - reference names through their module (fully qualified identifiers),
> - import a long module using a shorter name (alias; recommended),
> - or explicitly import just the names you need.

I follow #1 or #2, and never #3, for exactly the reason your program didn't work:

```
import os
import time

modTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("t.txt"))
print "t.txt was last modified at: " + modTime # This works now!
```

An example of #2 is:

```
import time
from datetime import time as dt_time
```

so `time.` means something from the `time` module, and `dt_time` is the function `datetime.time()`, and the name ambiguity is eliminated.

Undoubtedly people will disagree with this as being too pedantic, but it does keep you out of import trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you elaborate on #2 and why people would disagree with the pedantic attitude?

Comment: IMHO (and according to PEP8, please fix the link :)) `from x import y` is OK, you should just never do `from x import *`.

Comment: @undroid there you have an example of the differing opinions on how to  use imports. it was exactly `from x import y` that got you in to trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your corrected imports:

```
import os
from os import path
import time
from datetime import datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i tried it using version 3.5 and watched the tutorial about time module on youtube where the lecturer using 2.7 maybe.here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
c = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("file"))
print(c)
```

but actually i got the error post above and the right code is:

```
import time
c = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("file"))
```

because in python3.5, time is a individual module and does not in the date time module.and here is the snippet of time module source code.
[image: actually a build-in module]